# python - set empty list index into to 0

Tags: python, list

How do I detect an empty index and set an empty index in a list to 0 so it doesn't result in that error.  I'd like to set any index that is empty to 0.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6,7]

for x in range(len(l2)):
    print (x," ", l1[x])
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/desktop/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print (x," ", l1[x])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

result

```
1, 2, 3, 0
```

I know I'm accessing an index not there.

Comment: Yes because it's a larger function that this is an excerpt of where the other lists have 4 values.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? ``IndexError`` *is* the way to see that an index is not inhabited.

Comment: prior to this I'm using and re.findall to find a value and add it to the list.  Sometimes the value in a data set is not found so I'd like to be able to sent an index in the list to 0 instead of blank if the

Answer (score 3):

You can extend `l1` so that its length is the same as `l2` first:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6,7]
l1.extend([0] * (len(l2) - len(l1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of .extend() inbuilt function will modify your existing list l1, so your l1 = [1,2,3,0] at the end. but if you don't want to modify the list and will be not be using the inbuilt function, then we can do the below either way,

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6,7]

for x in range(len(l2)):
    if x < len(l1):
        print(x," ",l1[x])
    else:
        print(x," ",0)
```

Output will be:

```
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  0
```